# Probability -dividing into groups

Tags: probability

In how many ways can 12 people be separated into 3 groups of 4 if the 12 comprises 6 pairs of partners? We must keep partners in the same group, but we do not distinguish between the group $(a, b, c, d)$ and the group $(a, c, b, d)$.

Anyone can guide me for this? Thank you!

Comment: Are the partners relevant? Do you need to keep partners together?

Comment: yeah should be, though question didnot state

Comment: Are you counting {a,b,c,d} as distinct from {a,b,d,c}?

Comment: @PatrickStevens nope just need 4 people(2partners) in each group

Comment: @PatrickStevens can guide me? thx

Comment: Essentially 6 pairs have to be split into 3 groups. Does this simplify the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If the groups were labelled, one way you could divide the 6 pairs into 3 groups is ${6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}$,

but the groups aren't labelled, so what do you now need to do ?

> Divide by 3!